# Problema al separar un String en 3 partes con Scanner - Java

Tags: java, string, scanner

Holaa, el problema que tengo es al intentar separar en 3 partes una cadena de texto, bien lo que quiero hacer es que el Scanner lea un archivo de texto botones.txt que contiene el nombre del botón, posición "X" e "Y", creo el scanner y todo lo que hay en el archivo se imprime correctamente, pero al intentar separar en 3 me salta error diciendo "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1"

Aqui el codigo que intente, muchas gracias:

```
    File archivo = new File("C:\\.pruebas"+botones);
    
    s = new Scanner(archivo);
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String linea = s.nextLine();
        
        String[] cadena1 = linea.split(";");
        String parte1 = cadena1[0]; // Hola
        String parte2 = cadena1[1]; // 10
        
        String[] cadena2 = parte2.split("-");
        String parte3 = cadena2[0]; 
        
        String[] cadena3 = parte2.split("-");
        String parte4 = cadena3[1]; // 20
        
        System.out.println(parte1);
        System.out.println(parte3);
        System.out.println(parte4);
        
    }
```

Al hacer esto me tirra un error que dice "Index 1 out of bounds for length 1" pero al hacer lo mismo pero sin el Scanner en la clase main la cadena se divide en:

```
System.out.println("ABRIR");
System.out.println("20");
System.out.println("30");


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "CERRAR" + ";" + "20" + "-" +"30";
    String[] cadena1 = string.split(";");
    String parte1 = cadena1[0]; // Hola
    String parte2 = cadena1[1]; // 10
    
    String[] cadena2 = parte2.split("-");
    String parte3 = cadena2[0]; 
    
    String[] cadena3 = parte2.split("-");
    String parte4 = cadena3[1]; // 20
    
    System.out.println(parte1);
    System.out.println(parte3);
    System.out.println(parte4);
    
    
}
```

Alguien me sabe porque pasa y como podría arreglar esto o cambiar para que el Scanner lea la cadena y las separe los datos se separan por ; y -

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el archivo de texto tiene líneas vacías y el escáner las lee, y cuando se hace el `split()` se produce el error.

Luego de leer la línea se puede validar si está vacía y tomar alguna acción.

```
String linea = s.nextLine();
if(linea.isEmpty()) continue; // continuar con la siguiente iteración
```